# How do I extract "Mail Universal Distribution Group" from Exchange using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, exchange-server-2010

I can easily get all of the normal user-based mailboxes from Exchange using code like this:

```
Public Sub GetOutlookExchangeUserInformation()

    ' Variable declarations.
    Dim olApp           As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNameSpace     As Namespace
    Dim olAddrList      As AddressList
    Dim olAddrEntry     As AddressEntry
    Dim olExchgnUser    As ExchangeUser
    Dim sh              As Worksheet
    Dim lCnt            As Long

    ' Set the Outlook object variables
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olAddrList = olNameSpace.AddressLists("Global Address List")

    ' Create a new worksheet.
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    ' Add some headers for our data.
    With sh
        .Cells(1, 1) = "NAME"
        .Cells(1, 2) = "FIRST NAME"
        .Cells(1, 3) = "LAST NAME"
        .Cells(1, 4) = "ALIAS"
        .Cells(1, 5) = "JOB TITLE"
        .Cells(1, 6) = "DEPARTMENT"
        .Cells(1, 7) = "EMAIL"
    End With

    ' Start the counter in the second row.
    lCnt = 2

    ' Iterate through the address entires in the address list.
    For Each olAddrEntry In olAddrList.AddressEntries

        Set olExchgnUser = olAddrEntry.GetExchangeUser

        ' Turn off error handling, because occasionally you hit a
        ' record with nothing in it and it throws an error.
        On Error Resume Next

        ' Write the Outlook data to the worksheet.
        With olExchgnUser
            sh.Cells(lCnt, 1) = .Name
            sh.Cells(lCnt, 2) = .FirstName
            sh.Cells(lCnt, 3) = .LastName
            sh.Cells(lCnt, 4) = .Alias
            sh.Cells(lCnt, 5) = .JobTitle
            sh.Cells(lCnt, 6) = .Department
            sh.Cells(lCnt, 7) = .PrimarySmtpAddress
        End With


        Application.StatusBar = "Processing record " & lCnt & "..."

        If Err.Number = 0 Then lCnt = lCnt + 1
        ' Clear any error.
        Err.Clear
        ' Reset the error handling.
        On Error GoTo 0

    Next olAddrEntry

    ' Clear the status bar.
    Application.StatusBar = ""

    ' Prompt the user that we've finished.
    MsgBox "Extract done."

End Sub
```

(Reference to Microsoft Outlook required for the above to work)

I need to retrieve all of the `Mail Universal Distribution Group` items that I can see in Exchange. They are listed under `Recipient Configuration > Distribution Group` and all I really need is the name + email address.

I tried changing references to `olExchgnUser` to the below:

```
Dim olExchgnDL      As ExchangeDistributionList
Set olExchgnDL = olAddrEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList
```

This only returned the very last distribution group in the list. Is there a way to return all of them in a similar way to getting all of the user mailboxes?